# Using Select statement within a IIF function

Tags: sql, excel, subquery, iif

I'm trying to get the last 20 records if there is no "bit" in a column and if there is a "bit" I want to get the records that are after the record with a bit. In my example is "dry dock" string in the Comments column.
That's my SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    [Date], 
    [Lift ID]
FROM [Input Data$]
WHERE [Vessel name]='" + shipName + "' 
    AND [Lift ID] >= Iif(
                            (
                                SELECT max([Lift ID]) 
                                FROM [Input Data$] 
                                WHERE [Vessel name]='" + shipName + "' 
                                    AND [Comments] LIKE '%dry dock%'
                            ) >=1;
                            (
                                SELECT max([Lift ID]) 
                                FROM [Input Data$] 
                                WHERE [Vessel name]='" + shipName + "' 
                                    AND [Comments] LIKE '%dry dock%'
                            );
                            1
                        )
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

I'm getting the VBA Run-time '-2147217900 (80040e14)' error message "[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error in query expression ..."

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I recommend writing your test queries with LinqPad and then pasting it in to your program after it shows the correct results in LinqPad: https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Make your nested query a separate query `LikeDryDock`

```
    SELECT max([Lift ID]) 
    FROM [Input Data$] 
    WHERE [Vessel name]='" + shipName + "' 
        AND [Comments] LIKE '%dry dock%'
```

Then call that query inside the other one

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    [Date], 
    [Lift ID]
FROM [Input Data$]
WHERE [Vessel name]='" + shipName + "' 
    AND [Lift ID] >= Iif(
        LikeDryDock >= 1, LikeDryDock, 1
    )
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: Oh, I missed AND while writing a question. Actually it is in the code.

Comment: have you tested each part of this query separately? Each of those SELECT statements should produce a value you can see to debug.

Comment: Yes, i've tested all of the separately. An error occurs only when I use the IIF function (and SWITCH too)

Comment: Um... are the semicolons after each part of the IIF correct? Shouldn't they be commas? (e.g., `>=1,` rather than `>=1;`)

Comment: @seanb is right. When you look at the IIF you can see only one of the three parameters is satisfied. It needs 3 things separated by commas.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `WHERE` filter twice.